# biblatex style authoryear-luh-ipw broken with latest MikTeX

Tags: biblatex

After updating to the most recent MikTeX I find that running `pdflatex` on this document:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear-luh-ipw]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

fails with error

```
... MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\engli
sh.lbx")

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Examining `... MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-luh-ipw\lbx\english-luh-ipw.lbx` I see

```
% english-luh-ipw.bbx, Oliver Heins (oheins@sopos.org) 2012--2013

\ProvidesFile{english-luh-ipw.lbx}[2013/11/18 v0.3 bibliography localization for use with biblatex 2.x]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}

\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \savecommand\mkbibvolume
  \protected\def\mkbibvolume#1{\bibstring{jourvol}\adddot~#1}}

\UndeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \restorecommand\mkbibvolume}

\NewBibliographyString{issue}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  issue            = {issue}{iss\adddot}},

\endinput
```

Thinking that the trailing `,` at the end of `DeclareBibliographyStrings` looked out of place, I removed it as saved the file to my local `texmf` tree, and indeed it appears to solve the problem. Is this a bug in `biblatex-luh-ipw`? If so, is removing the trailing comma an appropriate fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.lbx` files of [`biblatex-luh-ipw`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-luh-ipw) contain a syntax error in the `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` declaration. Earlier `biblatex` versions would suffer in silence and not raise an error. `biblatex` v3.11 is more outgoing and issues an error message (unfortunately, that error message is not very helpful). The correct syntax is

```
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit      = {<language>},
  bibstring_1  = {{<short_1>}{<long_1>}},
  bibstring_2  = {{<short_2>}{<long_2>}},
               .
               .
               .
  bibstring_n  = {{<short_n>}{<long_n>}},
}
```

The key `inherit` is special and only takes one language in braces. All other keys are pre-defined bibliography strings and take one pair of braces containing the long and short form of the translation in a pair of braces each.

This means that the `.lbx` files should look like this.

**`german-luh-ipw.bbx`**

```
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {german},
  issue            = {{Heft}{H\adddot}},
}
```

**`english-luh-ipw.lbx`**

```
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  issue            = {{issue}{iss\adddot}},
}
```

You should definitely report this to the package maintainer, but given the fact that the package has not been updated in four and a half years, I'm not sure if he is still active.

Comment: Thanks @moewe I've reported the issue to the package maintainer.